# add trailing slash to slug url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite condition 
I use it to grab the slug url and search for a blog post like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/blog/my-first-post
```

So I grab the slug and then look for the post and display it.
Right now it accepts this two forms

```
http://localhost:8080/blog/my-first-post
http://localhost:8080/blog/my-first-post/
```

How should I change the .htaccess so it always adds or redirects with  the slash at the end.

And how should I change it to remove the slash always?

Here is the .htaccess I have now which I have it in the blog directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your current htaccess code by this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/

    # add trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

    # remove trailing slash
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Right now, it adds trailing slash. If you want to remove it, **comment** `add trailing slash` block lines and **uncomment** `remove trailing slash` block lines

Comment: Thanks but it takes me a directory up 
from http://localhost:8080/blog/my-first-post to 
http://localhost:8080/my-first-post/
Perhaps I wasn't specific.

Also could you give me a brief explanation or linke me to somwhere I can start learning about this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry i totally missed your htaccess was in `blog` folder. You can try my edited answer. You'll have to clear your browser's cache before trying again because old rule (without `blog`) is now in cache. If you want to learn `mod_rewrite` the better is to check Apache official doc here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: almost there! :D
Now it redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/blog/index.php/?url=my-first-post/` I have the .htaccess in the blog directory 
I plan on having the blog in a subdirectory on a page so that's why.

Comment: Now it works Thanks!
I'll start studying on that regex and .htaccess

Comment: if later I wanted to have `blog/categories/monkeys` 
I would have to drop another htaccess in the categories directory?
Or I would have to change this one?

Comment: That's up to you. You have both possibilities, it depends on what you want to do. The easiest to choose is the easiest for you to implement